# fuelphp - file extensions

Tags: fuelphp

I made a controller named sitemaps and have action_sitemap() , but how do I tell fuel to handle the following?:

```
http://site/sitemaps/sitemap.xml
```

and the following using the same action_sitemap() ?:

```
http://site/sitemaps/id.xml
```

where id could be a passed variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use routing, setup a route for both that you point to a controller method of your choosing.

Routing is explained [in the docs](http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/routing.html).

Put something like this in your routes.php app config file:

```
'sitemaps/sitemap\.xml' => 'sitemaps/sitemap',
'sitemaps/([0-9]+)\.xml' => 'sitemaps/sitemap/$1',
```

Comment: I configured routing before and I completely forgot that I saw this this type of example before, thank you so much!